# Mapping common data in python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I am reading csv file using `DictReader()` which has a data something like below,

```
NAMES,DATA
Name1,abcd
Name1,efgh
Name1,fgdh
Name2,xjbjk
Name2,flfnd
```

I am reading it and taking out in two list,

```
L1 = ['Name1','Name1','Name1','Name2','Name2']

L2 = ['abcd','efgh','fgdh','xjbjk','flfnd']
```

But I want Name1 to be mapped with its corresponding data, like below(or in some other format so that I can iterate over that to fetch some specific value)

```
{'Name1':['abcd','efgh','fgdh'], 'Name2':['xjbjk','flfnd']}
```

Could any one suggest any way to proceed with this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please post your attempt in the question as well

Comment: I suggest to create a dictionary and to append each value to a list stored in the dictionary using the name as the key.

Answer (score 2):

`DictReader` gives you a dict to start with. Build up your result row-by-row, instead of splitting your input into two lists.

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
get_pair = itemgetter("NAME", "DATA")

with open("tmp.csv") as f:
    d = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in d:
        name, value = get_pair(result)
        result[name].append(value)
```

The `defaultdict` ensures that `result[name]` is a list the first time you try to use `name` as a key. `get_pair` is a function equivalent to

```
def get_pair(d):
    return d["NAME"], d["DATA"]
```

Comment: what is the defaultdict here? Is it a dictionary which I need to define? Because I am getting  error:- NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, that was the reason for importing the `collections` module. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your two lists ...

```
L1 = ['Name1','Name1','Name1','Name2','Name2']
L2 = ['abcd','efgh','fgdh','xjbjk','flfnd']
```

This works:

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(L1, L2):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Like so:

```
>>> d
{'Name1': ['abcd', 'efgh', 'fgdh'], 'Name2': ['xjbjk', 'flfnd']}
```